# Joining attribute of smaller polygon to attribute of biggest polygon when they are overlapping

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, overlapping-features

I have two shapefile layers which include polygons. Each polygon on the first shapefile overlaps a polygon on the other shapefile.

I am trying to join the attribute of smaller polygons to the overlapping bigger polygons. I have used spatial join, but the attribute table of the bigger polygon is not showing the correct attributes of the smaller polygons inside it. I figured out there are some tiny polygons inside each polygon.

How can I join the attribute of the biggest overlapping polygon to the other shapefile?

[image: This is a snapshot of polygons]

Comment: While the *centroid* of the smaller polygon is inside the larger polygon, the geometries themselves are *not* always inside.

Comment: @Vince thanks for your comment, so there is no way to do this?

Comment: A spatial join should work, [have a look at the "match option" parameter](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/tool-reference/analysis/spatial-join.htm).  Hint: "HAVE_THEIR_CENTER_IN" will use the centroid.

Comment: Thanks for your replay, I have tried this but it is not working. I figured out there are some very small polygons inside the bigger one, do you know how can I join the attribute of the biggest polygon to the polygon that they are inside it?